# How do you find web fonts with good support for the OpenType frac feature?

Tags: css, web-fonts, opentype

I'm working on a website that'll have fractions in it, and I'd like to use the OpenType `frac` feature to format them well. CSS provides the [`font-variant-numeric:diagonal-fractions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-variant-numeric) property to turn this on, but fonts vary greatly in their support for this property, and it's hard to search for ones that do a good job.

As described in https://github.com/w3c/font-text-cg/issues/34, there are 3 practically different ways that fonts can support the feature:

1. Ligatures to combine strings like "1/3" into "⅓". These fonts tend to break improper fractions like `<span style="font-variant-numeric:diagonal-fractions">22/7</span>`, turning it into "2²⁄₇".
2. Fonts that treat all numbers as numerator numbers, unless they're between "/" and a space. These break mixed fractions marked up as `<span style="font-variant-numeric:diagonal-fractions">1 1/2</span>`, turning them into "¹ ¹⁄₂".
3. Good fonts, which in addition to handling both of the above cases, render mixed fractions with a hairline space instead of a full-width space, so `<span style="font-variant-numeric:diagonal-fractions">1 1/2</span>` looks like "1 ½" instead of "1 ½".

Some font searches, like [MyFonts](https://www.myfonts.com/pages/sans-serif-fonts?page=1&refinementList%5Bfont_data.advanced_typography%5D%5B0%5D=Fractions), can search for fonts that include the `frac` feature, but they don't distinguish whether the font is any good at the feature.

Some fonts, like [Lato](https://www.latofonts.com/lato-free-fonts/), are even available in multiple versions, where some versions handle fractions well, and others omit the `frac` feature.

I've found instructions for [InDesign tools](https://creativepro.com/formatting-fractions/), which will scan your text for fractions, and synthesize the right formatting even for fonts that don't support fractions, but of course an InDesign tools won't work as-is on a webserver.

So, how do the professional designers make fractions look good on the web?